# Vamos fazer um esforço para usar uma escrita neutra nas traduções?

Tags: debate, tradução

Estou vendo que estamos migrando de ferramenta de tradução e acho que é uma boa oportunidade de sugerir que tentemos manter uma **escrita neutra**.

**Mas o que é isso?** 
O inglês é uma escrita geralmente sem gênero, no sentido de que uma mesma frase frequentemente já se dirige a homens quanto mulheres. 
O que não é o caso do português.

Então na hora de traduzir, gostaria de sugerir que tentemos colocar **palavras neutras** (ex: "Quem pergunta..." no lugar de "O usuário que pergunta...") ou, quando não for possível, **colocar os dois gêneros** ("o(a)s usuário(a)s...").

Assim a gente faz com que as mulheres se sintam muito mais bem-vind**a**s aqui. ;)

Comment: +1, se tratando  da tradução, esse é um cuidado extra (com custo baixo) que tornará o site mais inclusivo.

Comment: Fiz um comentário aqui que expressava a minha opinião sobre o assunto. Ele foi apagado. Gostaria de saber a razão. Terá sido por não concordar, por ter falado o que a ministra da família disse ou por ter usado o "bom e velho" português?

Comment: @ramaral, não cheguei a ler o seu comentário. Cheguei porém a ler um comentário de outro usuário falando de não tentar polemizar o site com o que, na opinião dele, seria um "feminismo" na tradução. O JNat inclusive mudou o título original da pergunta. Se você discorda da iniciativa talvez valha a pena postar uma resposta dizendo isso. Eu porém não tenho nada contra o uso de dois géneros nas traduções oficiais, isso é comum e dá inclusive uma impressão profissional para o site. Veja também que isso não afeta o conteúdo em si, você não precisará usar pronomes neutros em respostas e perguntas.

Comment: O comentário, @ramaral, foi removido por mim por ser pouco amigável e utilizar um tom não construtivo :)

Comment: @JNat Não considero que ela fosse "pouco amigável", e não era essa a minha intenção. Quanto ao "não construtivo" até posso considerar que seja(aqui claro). No entanto existem outros comentário não construtivos, que não foram apagados.

Comment: `Assim a gente faz com que as mulheres se sintam muito mais bem-vindas aqui. ;)` - e quando nao foram bem vindas? Nunca presenciei ou fiquei sabendo de nada desrespeitoso a mulheres aqui no site, até porque o respeito deve existir independente de gênero. O site é aberto a todos participarem, não consigo enxergar como o emprego do português pode afastar alguém por causa de um artigo.

Comment: O teu comentário, @ramaral, simplesmente não foi feito de acordo com o espírito do [Código de Conduta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/conduct) — por isso é que o removi. Há maneiras de discordar construtivamente, e na verdade o Anthony convida-te a fazê-lo numa resposta uns dois comentários acima deste. Em relação a comentários que são tangenciais à discussão em causa: podes sempre sinalizá-los ;)

Comment: "(...) como o emprego do português pode afastar alguém por causa de um artigo," @ArticunoL, é uma maneira redutora de expôr a situação: o debate à volta deste tópico incide sobre como _a língua é um reflexo da sociedade que a usa_, mais do que se um artigo é descriminador por si só. Em relação à primeira metade do comentário: o facto de nunca ter sido claro para ti não quer dizer que não aconteça, e para além disso o pedaço de texto que citas fala de mulheres _sentirem-se_ mais bem-vindas — um distinção relevante. (1/2)

Comment: De qualquer modo, isto é uma discussão que pode ser bastante longa, portanto aconselho-te a publicares uma resposta ou uma outra pergunta sobre o assunto, se quiseres que a discussão se prolongue nesse sentido, sobretudo porque é ligeiramente tangencial a esta. Aconselho que faças uma busca no MSO antes, uma vez que isto foi discutido por lá também, antes :) (2/2)

Comment: Eu nao vou responder nada, porque pra mim esse tipo de assunto não deveria ser discutido aqui. Já temos o codigo de conduta, quem nao seguir que seja punido, não precisamos trazer esse tipo de discussão pra um site de programação.

Comment: @ramaral gostaria de ver uma resposta sua, mesmo que curta.

Comment: @Maniero Não vou responder porque o que eu penso já foi dito no comentário.

Comment: @ramaral uma pena porque ele era bom. Ainda que ele tivesse um tom não tão adequado (mas não sendo ofensivo ou desrespeitoso) e a pergunta também não era em tom muito bom, a pergunta foi editada, o comentário foi apagado. Mas eu compreendo sua reação. Mas é bom ter alguém que pensa que não é a língua que discrimina e sim a atitude das pessoas (todas elas, até as que parecem combater a discriminação e fazem o oposto). Defender igualdade era algo tão bom, agora virou religião, e por isso se discordar você está errado.

Comment: É isso mesmo @Maniero. O problema é que eu sou uma pessoa pragmática e não tenho jeito para "florear" o que escrevo. Pena, porque Isso deu o pretexto para que o comentário tenha sido apagado

Comment: Só digo que infelizmente, a língua portuguesa evoluiu a partir da idade média impondo o artigo masculino como o neutro em muitos contextos. Um exemplo simples: o pronome "elas" é usado para referir-se a um grupo exclusivamente de mulheres enquanto que "eles" é usado tanto a um grupo exclusivamente de homens como a um grupo que misture homens e mulheres. Complica o fato de que substantivos também têm gêneros atribuídos arbitrariamente mesmo que nada tenham a ver com o conceito de feminino/masculino. No inglês, artigos e substantivos não têm gênero e aí fica mais fácil para eles.

Comment: @VictorStafusa Será essa a razão? A língua turca(século VIII) é completamente neutra em relação ao género dos pronomes e todos sabemos o que lá se passa, e sempre se passou, em termos de inclusão. Em parte você tem razão, a perda do neutro se deveu à [evolução da língua](http://cvc.instituto-camoes.pt/hlp/gramhist/morfologia.html), mas não pela razão que indicou.

Comment: @ramaral Não estou querendo falar que a língua é a causa de haver ou não haver inclusão. Só estou querendo dizer que escrever um texto que seja perfeitamente neutro de gênero em português é razoavelmente difícil porque a língua portuguesa atribui gênero a tudo e usa o masculino como padrão.

Comment: @VictorStafusa Quando fiz a pergunta: "Será essa a razão?" referia-me à razão que apontou para a língua portuguesa impor o masculino como neutro. Não tem haver com  "evoluiu a partir da idade média".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Isto é uma excelente ideia!** Concordo que isto devia ser uma preocupação, e por isso mesmo quando traduzi [o Código de Conduta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/conduct) do inglês tive essa preocupação, e com a ajuda da equipa de moderação acho que chegámos a uma versão bastante neutra*. Se comparares a versão portuguesa com [a inglesa](https://stackoverflow.com/conduct), a tradução não é sempre a mais directa por causa desta preocupação, mas conseguimos chegar a uma boa tradução, não demasiado complicada.

Digo "demasiado complicada" acima simplesmente porque como indicas na tua pergunta o inglês é naturalmente neutro e o português não, o que pode significar que por vezes é bastante complicado usar o tipo de linguagem que queremos duma forma simples e eficaz, coisa que o espaço limitado dos elementos de UI por vezes requerem.

Dito isto, parece-me que a primeira opção (usar palavras neutras) é mais "limpa" que a segunda (usar os dois géneros), e foi portanto o que fiz no Código de Conduta — na altura ainda debati com a equipa de moderação [outras soluções](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linguagem_neutra_de_g%C3%AAneros_gramaticais#Propostas_para_neutralidade_na_ortografia), que também nos pareceram não tão eficazes como a linguagem neutra que acabámos por usar.

---

*Neutra não só no que diz respeito ao género, mas também à "versão" do português usado — não foi fácil balançar tudo isto, mas parece-me que toda a gente ficou satisfeita com o resultado :)

Comment: Que trabalho sensacional vocês fizeram na tradução do Código de Conduta! Muito legal você trazer aqui para que sirva de referência. ;)

Comment: «mas também à "versão" do português usado» ia referir isso mesmo.

Comment: JNat usar um @ por exemplo para "tod@s" ou "@s usuari@s" não seria plausível?

Comment: Na altura não fizemos assim porque essa opção ainda causa muita fricção, e então eu optei pela solução visível na tradução que está actualmente em uso. Obviamente, aberto a debate, na minha opinião: se a comunidade gostar dessa solução, parece-me que poderia ser aplicada, sim.

Comment: Eu sou absolutamente contra o uso de @. Polui o texto tanto quanto, se não mais, em relação aos o(a)s e a(o)s.

Comment: Não sei em Portugal, mas no Brasil normalmente utilizam "x" pra isso, entendeu *manx*? @JorgeB.

Comment: @Renan nunca tinha visto isso, parece-me estranho ;) O @ é muito mais intuitivo a meu ver.

Comment: @JorgeB. normalmente é a galera da lacração que usa, não sei se você está familiarizado com esse termo.

Answer (score 8):

- Quem abriu esta discussão é uma das principais colaboradoras na tradução e revisão das strings de interface do site, talvez a pessoa que mais contribuiu com isso na história do site. Levem isso em conta.
- Talvez exceto pelo tom do título original, a discussão foi proposta em termos bastante cordiais, sem querer impor nada a ninguém, sugerindo que *tentemos* ter um cuidado a mais ao sugerir ou revisar traduções.
- Me parece uma sugestão sensata, ponderada e com pouco potencial de impacto negativo no site – vai afetar algumas strings e provavelmente poucos notarão a diferença; mas isso talvez faça a diferença para quem se importa.
- Nosso processo de tradução e revisão é colaborativo e tem duas instâncias de aprovação. A Carla poderia ter mexido nas strings sem nem trazer a discussão para cá, dificilmente causaria transtornos e provavelmente as edições seriam aprovadas. E, novamente, duvido que muita gente sequer perceberia.
- Trazer a discussão para cá pode ser interpretado de duas maneiras: (A) ela quis simplesmente ser democrática e não fazer nada sem antes discutir com a comunidade; ou (B) ela quis marcar uma posição, se posicionar politicamente – e isso não é palavrão, quer dizer simplesmente defender algo dentro de uma determinada comunidade.
- Provavelmente ela foi movida pelas duas coisas, isso só ela pode dizer. O que importa é que muita gente enxerga somente ou principalmente a parte B, por uma série de motivos que não dá pra debater aqui, e isso acaba gerando polêmica. Basta ver os votos na pergunta, nas respostas, e os qualificadores usados para descrever a iniciativa: 
  "desnecessário", "ridículo", "inútil", "bobagem", "complicado", "perda de tempo", entre outros.
- Pra mim, só o fato de existir esse tipo de reação desproporcional é um indicador de que a discussão tem importância – e aqui estou falando mais da sociedade como um todo do que do site.

Comment: Muito bons e válidos todos os seus pontos. Seu último ponto, mais que todos. 
Ao longo dos anos eu percebi que se alguém chega para discutir sem se dar ao trabalho de pesquisar sobre um assunto pouco conhecido, alegando que quando eu digo A é porque eu quis dizer B e C, eu prefiro deixar que ela aprenda com o tempo a ter um pouco mais de empatia e talvez tente entender como eu me sinto. 
O que eu disse: eu acharia legal que fizéssemos A, que não dá trabalho e pessoas se sentiriam bem. O que entenderam: quero que todo mundo faça A porque me deu na telha e meu objetivo é chegar até o Z.

Comment: Nem mais bfavaretto.

Comment: Excelente resposta. Eu complementaria trazendo para o escopo que a proposta é apenas sobre: 1) o uso de dois gêneros (e.g., "os usuários (as)"), o que é extremamente comum em textos profissionais; 2) o uso de pronomes mais "neutros" (e.g., nós). Isso não tem nada a ver com toda a discussão política que está no rolando no Brasil e nos EUA. Não está sendo proposto que comecemos a usar termos como "presidenta" e "humoristo", não está sendo proposto para inventarmos novos pronomes (substitutos do *ze*, *hir*, *his* em Inglês), apenas o bom e velho português.

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly Concordo em parte com você, porque acho que tem sim a ver com a discussão política.

Comment: @bfavaretto, eu acho que a coisa tomou rumos políticos (e as pessoas estão agindo  com paixão devido a convicções ideológicas); meu ponto acima, porém, é que o que está sendo proposto aqui não é a adoção de uma postura reformista da linguagem como pedem alguns movimentos políticos modernos, e sim o uso de técnicas bem comuns e aceitas para tornar a escrita mais inclusiva.

Answer (score 7):

Não posso responder por todos obviamente. Só vou colocar minha opinião. Se isto é importante, acho que poderia deixar tudo no feminino. Acho que fica mais fácil de ler do que o tempo tempo ficar lendo `o(a)` ou `a(o)` (vai ter que discutir qual vai primeiro).

Usa-se o masculino porque é sobre **o** agente. Mas pode se usar o feminino por ser **a** pessoa.

Pra mim não muda nada. Usar o artigo masculino ou feminino não é uma questão de misoginia, machismo ou feminismo, é só uma praticidade linguística.

Particularmente não me sentirei desrespeitado, inferiorizado,não verei qualquer conotação negativa se usar só o feminino. Se há um grupo que precisa desta mudança para se autoafirmar podemos facilitar isso. Não estou dizendo que deveria fazer, mas que eu acho aceitável, não me causa problemas. Pelo menos causa menos que ver um parenteses em todas palavras que tenha variância de gênero na nossa língua, algo que já foi consagrado de como resolver. E que usa-se a dupla indicação nos casos onde precisa desambiguar que serve aos dois gêneros, quase sempre em documentos formais que serão usados para dirimir litigâncias.

Mas qualquer decisão será boa pra mim, não muda minha vida, a não ser ter mais dificuldade para ler. E tenho dislexia, por isso vai me criar complicações (já pensaram em pessoas como eu?), mas não uso isto para impor nada a ninguém, eu me viro com isto. É o mundo está ficando complicado, e cada vez mais porque tem que atender as necessidades de todo mundo, e tem muita gente com necessidades especiais. Ou pode-se ir sempre pelo caminho mais simples e só fazer exceções quando for muito necessário, quando realmente impõe grandes dificuldades para as pessoas, não dificuldades imaginárias. Mas em ambientes democráticos as pessoas podem optar pelo mais complicado.

Comment: Concordo discordando. Eu também senti algumas dificuldades, por vezes, com o pt-BR, até cheguei a ter problemas a entender alguns dos motivos possíveis para fechar perguntas. Se o texto poder ser mais neutro, melhor. Mas concordo que não se deve exagerar também, no caso de "o usuário" eu também preferia "o utilizador", mas não devemos entrar por esses caminhos perigosos do exagero que se vai vendo por ai...

Comment: @JorgeB. você se sente desrespeitado por usarem usuário e não utilizador? Você acha que seria melhor se tivesse as duas palavras?

Comment: Maniero foi exatamente isso que eu quis dizer, se fosse a agradar a todos seria "O(a) usuário(a)/utilizador(a)" e sabe-se lá mais o que. O que eu queria dizer, é que se der para ser mais neutro tudo bem, senão tudo bem na mesma. 

Poderia ser melhor, se, tivesse as duas alternativas no site, pt-PT e pt-BR pela localização ou por escolha, mas sei que é inconcebível num site desta dimensão. O mesmo com o feminino ou masculino. Há sites que fazem essa categorização dependendo do sexo escolhido na altura do registo...

Comment: Como disse acima, não me parece que usar a solução dos parêntesis seja a melhor maneira de resolver isto — só complica, e torna a leitura bem menos "limpa." Como dizes, até pode dificultá-la bastante para quem tem problemas como dislexia. Parece-me que soluções com palavras mais neutras, como proposto na pergunta e como acabámos por fazer no Código de Conduta é a melhor solução — é como dizes: limpo, não complica, e mais importante acaba por ser mais inclusivo para toda a gente e (não me parece) exclusivo para ninguém.

Comment: @JNat é só um motivo a mais para eu não contribuir com a tradução, o processo é complicado demais e ficará mais ainda, mas novamente, quem for fazer assim tem meu apoio, assim como tem também quem não o fizer. Nem sei se esse apoio importa.

Comment: @JNat Consegue me explicar, talvez incluído isso na sua resposta, em como palavras "mais neutras" "acaba por ser mais inclusivo para toda a gente".

Comment: Parece-me implícito, @ramaral. No entanto, aqui vai: não me parece que usar, por exemplo, "Todas as pessoas..." em vez de "Todos..." exclua alguém; parece-me, na verdade, ser mais inclusivo — acho que é evidente o que quero dizer, não?

Comment: "Todos os seres humanos" parece bem inclusivo também. Mas não adianta discutir isso, existe claramente algumas pessoas que tomaram posição que há discriminação por causa do artigo usado, oque é uma enorme bobagem, mas como eu já disse, pra mim tanto faz, se as pessoas se sentem melhor assim pra mim tá bom. Acho que tem problemas reais melhores pra se apegar, mas é um direito de cada um se apegar ao que quiser. E não vi alguém falando em exclusão por usar o artigo feminino, disseram apenas que não inclui de verdade, ou pelo menos de forma relevante. Só espero que agrade a todos.

Comment: @JNat Devo também, no código das minhas respostas, usar `int quemUsa;` em vez de `int usuario`? E em relação a usar expressões do tipo "cada macaco no seu galho" ou outras que envolvam animais? Devemos também deixar de as utilizar? **Nota:** apenas quer deixar claro o meu ponto de vista, não é minha intenção parecer/querer ser ofensivo ou desrespeitoso.

Comment: A pergunta está a falar do interface, e não de impôr um estilo de escrita unificado para toda a gente que usa o site... ninguém está a querer mudar como escreves, @ramaral :)

Answer (score 7):

Meu eterno contra-exemplo: em japonês não existem marcações de gênero na linguagem escrita (como os artigos **O** e **A**), e ainda assim são notórias as diferenças sociais de gênero/sexo, para o Ben ou para o Mao. Então, sou reticente à ideia de que a mera linguagem transformará este em um local mais aconchegante a pessoas mais sensíveis.

Em termos práticos, há problemas que não compensam. O uso da flexão de gênero no masculino já é enormemente consagrado pelo uso, e certas tentativas deixam o resultado muito antinatural:

- intercalar artigos em parênteses: "O(a) aluno(a) que não apresentar seus afazeres aos(às) professores(as) terá seus direitos de revisão diante dos Conselheiros(as) suspensos";
- trocar as tais desinências por X: "X alunx que não apresentar seus afazeres axs professorxs) terá seus direitos de revisão diante dos Conselheirxs suspensos";
- trocar as tais desinências por E: "E alune que não apresentar seus afazeres aes professores terá seus direitos de revisão diante dos Conselheires suspensos";
- explicitar os dois gêneros: "O aluno ou aluna que não apresentar seus afazeres aos professores e às professoras terá seus direitos de revisão diante dos Conselheiros e Conselheiras suspensos";

Diga-se de passagem, já que estamos falando de inclusão e aconchego, estas alternativas quebram o fluxo de leitura, principalmente softwares de leitura de texto para cegos. Não sou cego e não sei quantos cegos usam a família Stack, mas não penso que é possível ignorá-los.

Não me parece muito inteligente  incluir mulheres às custas de excluir cegos e disléxicos. Mas deve ser porque não gosto do utilitarismo, hey!

Isto talvez não se aplique à última opção, pois o texto ainda é legível. Mas em termos práticos a prolixidade aumenta de forma sensível. Este tipo de texto só seria justificável se fosse por alguma ênfase, como por exemplo "Meninos e meninas devem ser igualmente bem tratados neste playground".

Resumindo: minha sugestão é limitar-se a usar palavras de gênero neutro (que não sejam despersonalizantes), e não tentar ir além disso.

Comment: Concordo com as suas sugestões, embora discorde dos argumentos :)

Answer (score 4):

Vim ter em conta o aspecto linguístico. No alemão os anúncios de oferta de trabalho são obrigatoriamente dirigidos aos dois géneros, homens e mulheres, isto é uma obrigatoriedade legal pelo menos nesta situação, na Alemanha.

Dito isto, este tipo de discurso está previsto na língua portuguesa e é de facto praticada, especialmente, em documentos de foro formal. Contudo, é raro encontrar o mesmo tipo de discurso em contexto não formal.

### Argumentos para não mudar

Eu posso argumentar, que ao empregar este tipo de discurso você está a mudar as expectativas das pessoas para encontrarem o mesmo tipo de discurso não só no mesmo site, mas assim como em sites diferentes. Contudo a realidade não se conformará às expectativas recém adquiridas por essas pessoas e elas vão ficar no mínimo confusas.

De certa forma parece-me ser contra produtivo empregar este tipo de discurso, quando o restante do conteúdo do site, que é também a maior parte do site, não segue a mesma regra. Quando todos os outros sites, livros, documentos, não fazem a devida distinção por norma.

A expectativa do usuário regular ao entrar neste site deverá ser encontrar um estilo de escrita similar ao quotidiano. E esse estilo de escrita, por norma, não inclui a distinção.

### Argumentos para mudar

Eu posso argumentar, que a documentação do site é formal o suficiente para ter em consideração a devida distinção entre os géneros. Pessoalmente, não sei até que ponto isso é verdade. Mas é uma possibilidade.

Posso argumentar também que há sempre possibilidade de melhorar o estilo de escrita no site e este ser eventualmente um dos aspectos a ser melhorado.

Posso argumentar que as pessoas poderiam-se sentir mais bem recebidas com este estilo de escrita, mas como argumentei anteriormente também as pode deixar confusas.

### Conclusão

A minha conclusão pessoal é que se calhar é melhor deferir e analisar esta possibilidade de mudança, consultando por exemplo a [comunidade de língua portuguesa](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/). Com certeza pessoas com maior conhecimento das formalidades da nossa língua poderão ajudar-nos a saber se está será ou não uma decisão sensata.

Comment: [Portuguese Language](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/) ;)