# Como o novo Código de Conduta (CoC) afeta o SOpt?

Tags: debate

Estava lendo o "Metão" e vi que o [novo *Code of Conduct (CoC)* foi lançado](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/334900/official-faq-on-gender-pronouns-and-code-of-conduct-changes) e é bem polêmico. (Edit: O post foi removido e pode ser visto no site [WayBackMachine](https://web.archive.org/web/20191023013715/https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/334900/official-faq-on-gender-pronouns-and-code-of-conduct-changes)).

Como o @hkotsubo falou, o novo FAQ do CoC pode ser visto no post [What does the Code of Conduct say about pronouns?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336364/what-does-the-code-of-conduct-say-about-pronouns) e a discussão sobre o novo Código de Conduta pode ser visto no post [Post for clarifications on the updated pronouns FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336366/post-for-clarifications-on-the-updated-pronouns-faq).

Sei que é algo novo e provavelmente ainda não temos muitas respostas para isso, mas creio que outros usuários também estão confusos em como isso afetará a nossa comunidade.

Então fica a dúvida:

**Como o novo Código de Conduta (CoC) afeta o SOpt?**

E também para discutir a opinião dos usuários do SOpt sobre o novo CoC.

Relacionado:

- [Vamos fazer um esforço para usar uma escrita neutra nas traduções?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7555/75104)

Comment: Acho que por enquanto temos que esperar: "*Q13: How does this apply to languages other than English? **For now**, while the intent of being inclusive and respectful of all gender identities applies to all our communities, the specific requirements around pronoun usage **apply only to English language sites**. As we determine best practices in other languages, we’ll work with those communities and update guidance for those languages.*" - isso dá a entender que ainda vão definir como será em português.

Comment: @hkotsubo são 2 vertentes aí. Talvez não afete em termos de linguagem, mas talvez provoque posturas de membros em relação à empresa como um todo (no sentido de ativismo, seja pró ou contra as mudanças e atitudes da empresa).

Comment: Só pra constar, no SO em inglês já começaram a surgir os primeiros problemas ([aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58336846) e [aqui](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/390301)).

Comment: Atualizando: o link que está na pergunta [foi deletado](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/336374/401803), e no seu lugar foi colocada [uma nova versão](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/336364/401803)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

De imediato não parece afetar inclusive porque temos regras gramaticais diferentes. E é dito que não se aplica para línguas diferentes do inglês.

Não posso deixar de aproveitar para dizer que embora seja respeitoso com algumas pessoas seguir aquilo é desrespeitoso com outras obrigá-las a fazer algo incorreto porque algumas pessoas querem assim. Inclusive desrespeitoso com religiões, que eu abomino, mas respeito. O mundo só será melhor quando houver respeito geral e lidar com as diferenças. Quando se adotar políticas que obrigam pessoas fazerem algo contra sua crenças é só uma forma de fascismo, não é a busca pela paz e respeito que dizem querer.

Eu entendo que cada um tem suas motivações e necessidades, mas quando elas esbarram em conflitos com motivações e necessidades de outras pessoas a solução nunca é obrigar uma parte ceder e ser obrigado a fazer algo que ela não quer. Viva a diversidade! Abaixo a hipocrisia. O respeito pelas pessoas independente do que elas nasceram ou escolheram ser não pode ser objeto de desrespeito das outras pessoas.

Por sorte ainda temos menos radicalismo no nosso país, mas eu acho que vai contaminar e logo terão pessoas exigindo o mesmo.

Comment: Acho ingênuo esse raciocínio de "galera, em vez de criar regras que tal a gente respeitar todo mundo?". Acho que a maior parte das pessoas tem boas intenções, acontece que nem todo mundo usa a mesma régua. 
Só pra reflexão, deixo o Paradoxo da Tolerância: "Se estendermos a tolerância ilimitada mesmo aos intolerantes, e se não estivermos preparados para defender a sociedade tolerante do assalto da intolerância, então, os tolerantes serão destruídos e a tolerância com eles."

Comment: Exatamente, o que eu falei é justamente para as pessoas não usarem a mesma régua, é ridículo um grupo de pessoas achar que todos devem usar a mesma e todos os outros são obrigados a aceitar o que este grupo determina. É exatamente de intolerância que estou falando. Existe hoje um grupo de pessoas que tomaram para si a verdade absoluta e todos devem ser intolerantes com quem pensa diferente. Este grupo passou a considerar que só a sua verdade serve a tal ponto que chama pessoas que não estão fazendo nada de errado de intolerantes sem olhar para si próprios.

Comment: Eu tenho tentado fazer que os tolerantes não sejam destruídos pelos intolerantes que acham que só a sua verdade serve. Não é fácil quando os intolerantes já determinaram na sua verdade absoluta que eles é que são tolerantes e os os que não aceitam esse verdade inventada (não corroborada por lei em lugar algum porque seria um absurdo e ameaça à democriacia, diga-se de passagem) é que seriam os intolerantes. O que eu prego é justamente não ser tolerante com o intolerante

Comment: Esse negócio de ser tolerante é um problema sério, principalmente se os usuários do site aceitarem qualquer coisa que vier de cima sem questionamento do mérito (não me refiro só aos acontecimentos recentes). Sempre defendi que se deixe claro quando for coisa da comunidade e quando for coisa tipo "nós queremos assim pq a empresa é nossa, quem não estiver contente que saia". Quando o segundo caso se disfarça de "ativismo do bem", chega a ficar um negócio ofensivo para algumas minorias (os realmente engajados com a comunidade). Ambos  são válidos, mas que se assuma quando é um ou outro claramente

Comment: carla, o paradoxo da tolerância é invenção de quem quer impor as suas regras de suposta tolerância. Se me obrigarem a fazer isto ou aquilo em nome da tolerância, ai sim estão a ser intolerantes. A tolerância não pode ser só para o que interessa. Este tipo de coisas faz-me lembrar o pessoal que diz que temos liberdade de expressão quando se expressa mas quando alguém pensa o contrário dele diz que é atentado à democracia.